# Ни одна из перегрузок метода "ExecuteAsync" не принимает 2 аргументов

Tags: c#

```
private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage s)
        {
            var msg = s as SocketUserMessage;
            if (msg == null) return;

            var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, msg);

            int argPos = 0;

            if (msg.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos))
            {
                 var result = await _service.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos);

                if (!result.IsSuccess && result.Error != CommandError.UnknownCommand)
                {
                    await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
                }

            }
        }
```

Я не знаю почему ExeciteAsync не принимает context и argPos объясните доходчиво в чем проблема, и как её решить.

Comment: не надо несколько раз задавать один и тот же вопрос

Comment: так, а шо я могу сделать когда мой вопрос игнорят по кд мне надо разобраться в чем дело, чтобы в будущем не допустить этой ошибки

Comment: Как минимум отвечать на уточняющие вопросы в комментариях, а не задавать точно такой же вопрос